# How to install Teamspeak 3 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, launcher, teamspeak

I was follwing [this video](http://youtu.be/fhG5H8KwZRM) but at some point the guy just right-clicked his desktop and had a "Create a starter" option, I don't have that option so I thought about making a launcher using:

```
sudo nano ~/.local/share/applications/teamspeak3.desktop
```

and entering the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Teamspeak 3
GenericName=Team Speak 3
Exec=/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/teamspeak_icon_2.png
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;Communication;
Comment=Teamspeak.
```

But after saving I don't see the launcher anywhere, am I doing something wrong?

Where can I get an application to make launchers as easy as the guy from the video?

Here's an image so you can see the location of the files:

[image]

I solved it, the only problem were some blank spaces inside the desktop entry, it should work fine for any of you too.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the only problem were some blank spaces inside the desktop entry.